# thymeleaf get first 3 objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Could you please help me.
I want to display my first 3 objects from product, I don't how it must be.
I try to use thymeleaf sequence, but it don't work. Maybe somebody can hint me how it could be done.

HTML:

```
<th:block th:each="product:${products}">

<a  th:class="production_Page" th:href="@{'product/'+${product.id}}"> <p 
th:text="${product.productName}"/></a>

<a th:class="production_Page" 
th:href="@{'productDelete/'+${product.id}}">Delete</a>

<a th:class="production_Page" 
th:href="@{'productEdit/'+${product.id}}">Edit</a>

<img  th:class="productImage" th:src="${product.pathImage}"/>
<br/>
</th:block>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public String seeAllProductsIntoAList(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("products", productService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
    return "/productView/products";
}
```

It would be great if somebody can hint me with this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: what will `productService.findAll()` return ?

Comment: @Override
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }

Answer (score 5):

Since `products` is list of `Product`, you have to iterate over that list. On thymeleaf you can use `th:each` attribute to do iteration. So for your case you can use something as below. Give it a try.

```
<th:each="product,iterStat: ${products}" th:if="${iterStat.index} <3">
```

I am not entirely sure but based on your question you wanted only first three objects. For this you can use status variable that are defined in `th:each`. More detail you can find [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way you do it with the `#{numbers}` context object.

```
<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, 2)}" th:with="product=${products[i]}">
    <a th:class="production_Page" th:href="@{'product/'+${product.id}}">
        <p th:text="${product.productName}"/>
    </a>

    <a th:class="production_Page" th:href="@{'productDelete/'+${product.id}}">Delete</a>
    <a th:class="production_Page" th:href="@{'productEdit/'+${product.id}}">Edit</a>
    <img  th:class="productImage" th:src="${product.pathImage}"/>

    <br/>
</th:block>
```